# in cesiumjs,how to draw the line which is the centeral axis of a frustum?

Tags: cesiumjs

[image: screenshot]

just the dashed arrow line in the picture, I can draw the frustum  with longtitude /latitude/altitude,and the HeadingPitchRoll info , but I have no idea to draw the dashed arrow line.
you guys ,have some ideas with that?
here is my code to draw a frustum with a real camera's infomations:

```
drawFrusrum({ lng, lat, alt, head, pitch, roll, fov, aspectRatio }) {
 // draw by the real camera's infomations :fov,ratio of aspect and position of WGS84
const origin = Cesium.Cartesian3.fromDegrees(lng, lat, alt);
const far = 200;
const hpr = new Cesium.HeadingPitchRoll(Cesium.Math.toRadians(head), Cesium.Math.toRadians(pitch), Cesium.Math.toRadians(roll));
const orientation = Cesium.Transforms.headingPitchRollQuaternion(origin, hpr);
const frustum = new Cesium.PerspectiveFrustum({
  fov,
  aspectRatio,
  near: 1.0,
  far
});
if (window.UAVFrusrum) {
  window.viewer.scene.primitives.remove(window.UAVFrusrum);
  window.UAVFrusrum = null;
}
window.UAVFrusrum = new Cesium.Primitive({
  geometryInstances: new Cesium.GeometryInstance({
    geometry: new Cesium.FrustumGeometry({
    frustum,
    origin,
    orientation
    //  vertexFormat: Cesium.VertexFormat.POSITION_ONLY
    }),
    attributes: {
    color: Cesium.ColorGeometryInstanceAttribute.fromColor(
      new Cesium.Color(0.0, 0.65, 0.7, 0.4)
    )
    }
  }),
  appearance: new Cesium.PerInstanceColorAppearance({
  //  closed: true,
  // self defined material
    material: new Cesium.Material({
    fabric: {
      type: 'Color',
      uniforms: {
        color: new Cesium.Color(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0), 
        glowPower: 0.5 
      },
      components: {
        diffuse: 'color.rgb * (1.0 - glowPower) + color.rgb * glowPower',
        alpha: '1.0'
      }
    }
    })
  })
});
window.viewer.scene.primitives.add(window.UAVFrusrum);
// TODO : to draw the centeral line 

}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please edit your question to include some sample code (perhaps for Cesium Sandcastle) that will render the frustum walls you're showing here. Then the folks here can offer suggestions on how to adapt that code to include the new line.